# Как переписать url ?id=1 на item/1 в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, чпу

Мне нужно переписать урлы такого вида

```
/blog/item/view_topic.php?id=1
/blog/item/view_topic.php?id=2
...
/blog/item/view_topic.php?id=100
```

на такой:

```
/blog/item/1
/blog/item/2
...
/blog/item/100
```

Что нужно прописать в файле *.htaccess*? Помогите, пожалуйста, для меня это темный лес.

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d)+
RewriteRule ^blog/item/view_topic.php$  /blog/item/%1
```

Comment: Это не работает. В `%{REQUEST_URI}` нет параметров GET-запроса. Они все в `%{QUERY_STRING}`.

Comment: Я уже поправил. Давно не брал в руки шашек :)

Answer (score 2):

Делается это, например, так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/item/view_topic.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /blog/item/%1? [L,R=301]
```

А если же нужно обратное преобразование, то так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blog/item/(\d+)$ /blog/item/view_topic.php?id=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Работает, но когда перехожу по ссылке, выдает "The requested URL /blog/item/1 was not found on this server".

Comment: @php_chainyk, так вопрос нужно верно формировать, а не обратным способом! Вам ответили так, как вы его задали: /blog/item/view_topic.php?id=1 --> /blog/item/1

Comment: @php_chainyk Так каталоги-то соответствующие создать надо. Или Вам нужна обратная задача?

Comment: @php_chainyk Добавил в ответ обратное преобразование.

Comment: Ну у меня view_topic.php отвечает за отображение постов в блоге.
Когда перехожу - /blog/item/1 ...  /blog/item/100  not found on this server.
Что нужно сделать, чтобы оно корректно работало?
Как эти каталоги создавать?

Comment: @php_chainyk Судя по вопросу, Вы и сами не понимаете что Вам нужно. Похоже, Вам нужен именно второй вариант.